# Is there any way of setting an android tab to act as a raspberry pi keyboard through a usb to micro usb cable?

Tags: keyboard

I need to set up my android tab to act as a keyboard for my raspberry pi 2 b+. I have the 7 inch touchscreen mount on the raspberry pi already so I don't need a display. I also have a USB to micro USB coming out of the pi and into the tablet to connect them. Is there any way of setting it up?

Comment: Your looking for a way of using a the keyboard built into your tablet as keyboard for the Pi? I can't see that working. I think you should give something like VNC Viewer a look.

Comment: Is that an app on android or the pi. Sorry I am pretty new to the raspberry pi.

Comment: Hi just looked at VNC, it's good but are there any ways of using the USB to Micro USB for the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: No, a stock android device cannot act as a keyboard.

Complex answer: According to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805731/is-it-possible-to-program-android-to-act-as-physical-usb-keyboard) you can modify the kernel on some android devices to make it act as a HID device and be a keyboard.

The code is on [github](https://github.com/pelya/android-keyboard-gadget).

I would not recommend it unless you have experience rooting your tablet and running non-stock android on it. Get a cheap USB keyboard.

Comment: OK thx for the answer